# Simple slider in jQuery only showing first two pictures after toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to create simple slider. When I click on a picture, the other one will be visible. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/intercoder/pen/2fbd825876fe4368bb3497b2dff5074b) with the code

Eventually I would actually like to create a carousel like function, that would loop through my items calling `.animate({scrollLeft}) ...` but I'm getting stuck in the loop implementation as well. But baby steps, right?

**EDIT:** Problem is I'm only toggling the first and then the second picture out of 4.

Here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<div class=container>
  <img class='isActive' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
  <img class='isHidden'src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

**index.scss**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
 // display: inline-flex;
}

.slide {

}

.isActive {
  visibility: visible;  
}

.isHidden {
 visibility: hidden; 
}
```

**index.js**

```
$(function() {
  var allImgItems = $('img');
  var items = $('.container').find(allImgItems);

  toggleVisibility = function(item) {    
    item.toggleClass('isHidden');
    item.next().removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive');
//    item.next().removeClass('isHidden').animate( { scrollLeft: 200 + 'px'}, '500', 'swing', function() {console.log('Animation completed') } );
    console.log(item);
  }

  toggleItem = function () {
    var item = $('img:first').click(function () {  // [QUESTION]The problem is here I think, since I'm just passing the first obj and not the list?
      toggleVisibility(item);
    })
  }
  toggleItem();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `event.currentTarget` parameter to click function to get current DOM element.
And than remove hide class `.isHidden` from next element, but add same class to that element.

If you click on a last element of slider, get back to first image and do what you need for him.
Check working code: [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoowYj)

```js
$(function() {


  var allImgItems = $('img');
  var items = $('.container').find(allImgItems);

  allImgItems.click(function(event, index) {

    var item = $(event.currentTarget)
    item.addClass('isHidden');
    item.next("img").removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive');
    item.next().removeClass('isHidden').animate({
      scrollLeft: 200 + 'px'
    }, '500', 'swing', function() {
      console.log('Animation completed')
    });

    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
      allImgItems.first("img").removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive');
    }

  });
})
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.slide {} .isActive {
  visibility: visible;
}
.isHidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <img class='isActive' src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```